# ember cannot put into the store from an adapter

Tags: ember.js, websocket, adapter, store

I m building a solution using Ember that will receive data in JSON format from an external server using websocket connection. I m going to use an adapter containing a socket. When receiving data from the server, I have an issue "pushing" my data into a `var store = this.get('store');`  doesn't work. the store is undefined in the adapter and so the line `this.store.push('post',data)` doesn't work too.

is there a way how to push my data into the store, am I missing something?
Can I get a working example to work with?

Comment: Can you give me a link of the question and the answer?

Comment: It is your previous question.  Just as a pro tip, when it's marked as a duplicate the duplicate answer is posted at the top of this question.